# Cython and SIMD intrinsic: preventing conversion to python object for SIMD intrinsic function's argument

Tags: python, cython, simd, intrinsics, avx

I've gotten some success in trying SIMD intrinsics thru cython. Right now I'm struggling to get the compare function in AVX to work because the compare function needed an argument that should not be converted to python object.

```
cdef extern from "immintrin.h" nogil:  # in this example, we use SSE2
    ctypedef float  __m256
    const int _CMP_GT_OS

    __m256 _mm256_loadu_ps  (float *__P) nogil  
    void   _mm256_storeu_ps (float *__P, __m256 __A) nogil
    __m256 _mm256_set1_ps   (__m256 __A) nogil
    __m256 _mm256_cmp_ps    (__m256 __A, __m256 __B, _CMP_GT_OS) nogil


@cython.boundscheck(False)      # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound (False)      # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
@cython.cdivision  (True )        
cdef void Example_v4 (float *A, float *B, float delx) :
    ### this example for A & B having exactly 8 elements

    cdef:
        __m256 mA, mB, mdelx, mOut
        float *out = <float*> malloc( 8 * sizeof(float)) 
        int i

    with nogil:
        mdelx = _mm256_set1_ps( delx )
        mA    = _mm256_loadu_ps( &A[0] )
        mB    = _mm256_loadu_ps( &B[0] )        

        mOut = _mm256_cmp_ps  ( mA, mB, _CMP_GT_OS )        
        _mm256_storeu_ps( &out[0], mOut )

    print ( " i     out  " )
    for i in range(8):
        print ( i, out[i] )
    return
```

The problem is when I compile the cython code, I get this part highlighted as the issue.

```
        mOut = _mm256_cmp_ps  ( mA, mB, _CMP_GT_OS ) 

with  ^ symbol pointing at _CMP_GT_OS
```

and message

```
Converting to Python object not allowed without gil
```

I believe the issue isn't gil, the intrinsic function is defined in official Intel documentation as

```
__m256 _mm256_cmp_ps (__m256 __A, __m256 __B, const int imm8)
```

imm8 can be of many type of Operations, with _CMP_GT_OS being one of them.
I don't know how to deal with 3rd argument and preventing it from converting to python since the intrinsic only recognize C/C++ const int. Any idea how to workaround this problem ?

Comment: What is the cdef type of `mOut`? I think that is why it is complaining about the conversion to a python object. Perhaps you meant `mOut1`?

Comment: This is probably typo: it should be mOut1 and not mOut (or other way around)

Comment: Yes, a typo. Sorry, I edited out some stuff to simplify for this question, forgot to change that. I'll edit it. But the problem is still as I describe.

Comment: Not sure if that is your problem, but the `_CMP_GT_OS` in `__m256 _mm256_cmp_ps    (__m256 __A, __m256 __B, _CMP_GT_OS) nogil` looks weird. Shouldn't that be `const int`?

Comment: When you wrap cmp_ps, you forgot to type third argument, and cython assumes it is object

Comment: I did do const int in the top part. But let me try it directly. I have some vague memory I tried that first and it fails miserably.

Answer (score 0):

I did two changes:
in the cdef extern part, I added a value to it. I am still not 100% certain how to use this function. So this is all trial and error but at least doing this way, I can move forward to check and do more trial and error.

```
cdef extern from "immintrin.h" nogil:  # in this example, we use SSE2
    ctypedef float  __m256
    const int _CMP_GT_OS = 14

    ## other definition like in the question
    __m256 _mm256_cmp_ps    (__m256 __A, __m256 __B, const int _CMP_GT_OS) nogil
```

Changing only the declaration in _mm256_cmp_ps part didn't work. I have to assigned it a value first.

Now it can compile without error and can be called and used in the python side. As for result, still strange, so I don't know if it's actually right or not this way. I'll report back when I understand more. In the meantime, feel free to chime in. Thank you.

Comment: If you can't use a C compiler's symbolic constants, look at the asm manual, which has a table of predicate numbers to names: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpps.  (`cmppd` is alphabetically first and thus earlier in Intel's original manual, and has a better table: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmppd).  But I don't think that was your problem, sorry nvm.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for trying to help. I'm getting NaN in the place for True. Doesn't feel right, I think based on SSE case, true is suppose to be -1.0. Need to find out more.

Comment: Lol, not `-1.0f`, you get all bits set to ones so you can use it with `_mm256_and_ps` or whatever to zero out or leave unmodified some elements of another vector.  That all-ones taken as a `float` bit-pattern represents a `-QNaN`

Comment: @PeterCordes , Tthank you Peter, taking your suggestion, everything works out well now. This is enough for now to completely rewrite an expensive computation part to use this. Hopefully I will see at least a 2x speedup. It is a little sad that the once easily read short code will now look very foreign and longer.